# Hook (`orm`) failed to load

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, orm, hook

Hello everyone I hope you all are doing well.

I am facing this issue for a long time can anyone helps me out with this, I will be really grateful to you all...

I don't even know why am I getting this error I mean the reason behind this.

[Please click here for the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ0i6.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I got my answer the syntax of my seed data was not correct, that's why orm was not able to export them.....

But now the issue is resolved.